# How to fix defining an 'invalid syntax' error Terminal when using Django to run a server (mac)

Tags: django

Hi I'm setting up a new server in Django using python and with the help of this tutorial `(file:///Users/matthewdeyn/projects/helloapp/howdy/templates/index.html)`.
When I try and run the server in terminal (using mac) I get a syntax error concerning the file: urls.py which was made previously in the tutorial.

I am new to coding and have tried to search for the answer on google but nothing yet. I also typed in the code for the file in question exactly so am unsure as to the solution.

```
# howdy/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from howdy import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^'$, views.HomePageView.as_view())
]
```

Expected results are that the server will run and previous HTML code will render when I load the webpage through http://127.0.0.1:8000/.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjeZG.png)

Comment: `r'^'$` should be `r'^$'`. Your dollar sign is outside regex string

Comment: And on screenshot you lost closing bracket of url pattern regex